# Automatically generating Webpack chunk names for dynamic imports

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I would like my webpack-generated JS chunk files to have the same name as the source filename.
I know I can achieve this by explicitely adding a magic comment like so:

```js
 import(/* webpackChunkName: "some-name" */ '@/components/profile/someName'),
```

but as we have hundreds of imports, I am looking for a way to do this via configuration instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you did your code splitting right, Webpack automatically generate the chunk with this format `src_[components-directory]_[component-file-name]_[component-extension].chunk.js`

for example you want to load src/pages/about-us.tsx, your chunk `src_pages_about_us_tsx.chunk.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure all webpack magic comments at build time with [`magic-comments-loader`](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader).

Simply adding the loader uses hyphenated filenames as the default chunk name:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['magic-comments-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```

The above would yield a chunk name of `@-components-profile-someName`.

If you just want the basename, then you can use `basename` when configuring the `webpackChunkName` option:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'magic-comments-loader',
        options: {
          webpackChunkName: {
            options: {
              basename: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That would result in a bundle of `someName.js`.

There's lots of other [options](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader#options) and [overrides](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader#overrides) are supported.